# I am missing some icons in KDE 5 launcher and tray after installing unity

Tags: unity, kubuntu, launcher, icons, kde

I have kubuntu 15.04 on my laptop.
Last night I installed unity desktop using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

on my laptop. But after restart I noticed  some of my application icons in KDE launcher menu and tray are gone. Applications without icons are still working properly in KDE but they have no icons! Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: Does manually setting a icon theme in `systemsettings5` (choose icons) change anything?

Comment: Add screenshot of the problem please

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the Unity desktop may not have the icon of that particular app. Install unity tweak from software center and change icon type. That should work